# Using SQlite to populate expandable list duplicating data into headers

Tags: java, android, sqlite, expandablelistview

I am trying to populate my expandable list from a SQLite DB, I got the expandable list tutorial from androidhive but it was for static data.

I got it working about 80% but now my problem is that the data gets populated under all the headers and not their unique headers. I think my problem is because all header and child data is using the same arrays and need to be unique to the headers?

What I was thinking was creating arrays dynamically with variable names but I have no idea how to do that and can't think of another way of doing this since this is my first time working with expandable lists.

Here is my code. I also have a feeling the way I am doing the nested cursors isn't the right way

```
String sqlQ = "SELECT Distinct "
            + "strftime('%d-%m-%Y', "+ SQLdb.DB_TIMEOPEN +") header " +
            " FROM " + SQLdb.DICTIONARY_TABLE_NAME
            + " WHERE " + SQLdb.DB_PACKAGE + " = '"+ appPackage +"'"
            + " ORDER BY " + SQLdb.DB_TIMEOPEN + " ASC";
    Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery(sqlQ, null);
    Log.i("SQL",sqlQ);

    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            listDataHeader.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex("header")));



            String sqlQ2 = "SELECT " + SQLdb.DB_NAME + ", "
                    + SQLdb.DB_PACKAGE + ", " 
                    + SQLdb.DB_TIMEOPEN + ", " 
                    + SQLdb.DB_TIMECLOSED + ", " 
                    + SQLdb.DB_DURATION + ", "
                    + "strftime('%d-%m-%Y', "+ SQLdb.DB_TIMEOPEN +") header " +
                    " FROM " + SQLdb.DICTIONARY_TABLE_NAME
                    + " WHERE " + SQLdb.DB_PACKAGE + " = '"+ appPackage +"'"
                    + " AND strftime('%d-%m-%Y', "+ SQLdb.DB_TIMEOPEN +") = '"+ mCursor.getString(mCursor
                            .getColumnIndex("header")) +"'"
                    + " ORDER BY " + SQLdb.DB_TIMEOPEN + " ASC";
            Cursor mCursor2 = dataBase.rawQuery(sqlQ2, null);
            if (mCursor2.moveToFirst()) {
                do {


                    listDataChildInner.add(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2
                                    .getColumnIndex(SQLdb.DB_DURATION)));
                    listDataChildInnerO.add(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2
                                    .getColumnIndex(SQLdb.DB_TIMEOPEN)));
                    listDataChildInnerC.add(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2
                                    .getColumnIndex(SQLdb.DB_TIMECLOSED)));
                    Log.i("ACT CHILDT",mCursor.getString(mCursor
                            .getColumnIndex("header")) + " -> " + mCursor2.getString(mCursor2
                                    .getColumnIndex(SQLdb.DB_TIMEOPEN)));
                } while (mCursor2.moveToNext());
            }


            listDataChild.put(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex("header")).toString(), listDataChildInner);

            listDataChildO.put(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex("header")).toString(), listDataChildInnerO);

            listDataChildC.put(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex("header")).toString(), listDataChildInnerC);


        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Comment: Facing same problem, didn't able to solve. :(